# Unexpected behaviour while setting a image from res folder to an image view in android

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I am using an imageview in my xml and setting an image from res/drawable-xhdpi to it. My image is of 354x404 in size and when i am running the code on a 10" samsung tablet, it showing the image as 177x202.

Here is the code which i am using:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:src="@drawable/android1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the image which i am using:

[image]

And this is the screenshot of the tablet:

[image]

Please tell why it is happening and what is the solution to resolve this problem.

**Update:** when i putting this image in "res/drawable" folder instead of xhdpi, it showing the image correctly i.e. 354x404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit after comments:**

The ImageView will render the image inside of it at the correct resolution for the device. As per the documentation on [providing resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources), you must make sure that you provide resources at the correct DPI for each of the resolution types. Android will pick the best resource resolution for you, but if only one resource exists then it will pick that one and try to render at the device resolution.

Samsung tablets, while they have a large screen, are MDPI (the Galaxy Tab 2, at least) which is the standard density even though it has a large screen. Resources for it should be placed in `res/drawable`.

Comment: Right now there is no other UI content is present on the screen then why it is scaling it down? what should i set as the width and height if "wrap_content" is creating problems.

Comment: If you manually set the size of the ImageView (or tell it to fill_parent) then you can configure scaling with [setScaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setScaleType%28android.widget.ImageView.ScaleType%29). Are you sure the image just does not appear smaller because of the DPI differences between the screens?

Comment: No.. i have used the images which are of 300dpi's. Plus when i am putting this image in "res/drawable" folder instead of xhdpi, it showing the image correctly i.e. 354x404.

Comment: Are you sure that the device you are using is an `xhdpi` device? I'm guessing 10" Samsung tablet means a Galaxy Tab 2, which is an MDPI device with an xlarge screen size (I think, tried googling it). If you are using images from the wrong screen type then they will be displayed at the wrong size. Does that help?

Comment: Thanks man! actually that was the problem. Samsung creates tablets of lower DPI's so that it can be cheap and creates problems for developers. Again thanks for the help.

Comment: So, to clarify, if you have an MDPI device, which is the 'standard', it should use the drawable from `res/drawables`. If the drawable only exists in one place (`res/hdpi`) then it will choose that and will render it incorrectly. This is why it looked small when you moved it into xhdpi. Have a quick look at the docs for [providing resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources) for more information.

Comment: I've updated the answer to reflect this so that newcomers will be able to find help more easily.