# Android drawable mdpi

Tags: android

I am working on a Android Project.

I put the images (320*480) into the mdpi -folder.  There are some information in Android developer site that 480*800 tablets(7") also takes images from the mdpi- folder. When the 7" tablet takes images form that mdpi- folder it become smaller. There is only one mdpi- folder so how do i exactly manage it .

Comment: is it splasscreen image ? i mean, you expect this image to fill the screen.

Comment: no it is not splash screen image. These images sre buttons, icons etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the Android developer documentation on [Providing Alternative Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources).

From my answer to this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14019637/unexpected-behaviour-while-setting-a-image-from-res-folder-to-an-image-view-in-a/14019668#14019668):

> The ImageView will render the image inside of it at the correct resolution for the device. As per the documentation on providing resources, you must make sure that you provide resources at the correct DPI for each of the resolution types. Android will pick the best resource resolution for you, but if only one resource exists then it will pick that one and try to render at the device resolution.

So, find out the correct DPI for your device, and add the image (at the correct DPI) into that folder and it should appear at the correct size. If the image is placed in the wrong folder then it will appear a different size. Another useful link is the [Density Independence](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#density-independence) documentation.

Note: let's assume your device is an HDPI device. The `res/drawables/drawable-hdpi` folder might not exit in your project but you can just add it in manually.

Answer (score 0):

you should create **ldpi, hdpi, xhpi** folder too. And you need to copy your image with same name by calculating its ratio.

```
ldpi - mdpi - hdpi - xhdpi 
 3      4      6      8
```

> There is a 3:4:6:8 scaling ratio between the four primary densities
>   (ignoring the tvdpi density). So, a 9x9 bitmap in ldpi is 12x12 in
>   mdpi, 18x18 in hdpi and 24x24 in xhdpi.
>
> If you decide that your image resources don't look good enough on a
>   television or other certain devices and want to try tvdpi resources,
>   the scaling factor is 1.33*mdpi. For example, a 100px x 100px image
>   for mdpi screens should be 133px x 133px for tvdpi.

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix up screen size with screen density. There are qualifiers related to screen size (e.g. small, normal, large, ...) and qualifiers related to density (e.g. ldpi, mdpi, ...).

You can even combine these qualifiers, for example in `drawable-normal-mdpi` you can put resources that will be used on devices with normal screen (phones) with a mdpi density.